Getting 401 on public page even if I am authorized
I am developing rest api for forum in spring boot. I have GET mapping on /api/v1/forum/threads, which will return all the threads. But it returns 401 Unauthorized when I try to access it, even if I am authorized.
Thread Controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/forum/threads")
public class ThreadController {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadService threadService;
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Thread>> getAllCategories(){
        List<Thread> threads = threadService.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(threads);
    }
}


Thread service:
@Service
public class ThreadService {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadRepository threadRepository;

    public Optional<Thread> findById(long id) {
        return threadRepository.findById(id);
    }
    public Optional<List<Thread>> findByName(String keyword){
        return threadRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(keyword);
    }
    public Optional<List<Thread>> findByCategory(Long id){
        return threadRepository.findByCategoryId(id);
    }
    public List<Thread> findAll(){
        return threadRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Optional<List<Thread>> findByContent(String keyword){
        return threadRepository.findByContentContainingIgnoreCase(keyword);
    }


    public void createThread(Thread thread){
        threadRepository.save(thread);
    }
    public void deleteThread(Long id){
        threadRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

Thread Repository:
@Repository
public interface ThreadRepository extends JpaRepository<Thread, Long> {
    Optional<Thread> findById(Long id);
    Optional<List<Thread>> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String title);
    Optional<List<Thread>> findByCategoryId(Long categoryId);
    Optional<List<Thread>> findByContentContainingIgnoreCase(String keyword);
}

Security config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/forum/threads/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return auth.build();
    }
}


JWT filter:
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final List<String> PUBLIC_URLS = List.of(
            "/api/v1/forum/categories/**",
            "/api/v1/forum/threads/**"
    );

    private final AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
            String path = request.getRequestURI();

            // Проверяем, является ли URL публичным
            boolean isPublic = PUBLIC_URLS.stream()
                    .anyMatch(publicUrl -> pathMatcher.match(publicUrl, path));

            if (isPublic) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            if (jwt != null) {
                if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt)) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                    String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
                    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                        System.out.println(2);
                        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "JWT claims string is empty");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication error");
        }
    }


    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

I thought that problem might be in JWT filter, which is not well writen, but it doesn't seem to be a thing. I have similar Get mapping on /api/v1/forum/categories, which returns all the categories without 401.
I tried modifying security config and thread controller. Here is my Categories Controller:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/forum/categories")
public class CategoryController {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadCategoryService threadCategoryService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ThreadCategory>> getAllCategories(){
        List<ThreadCategory> categories = threadCategoryService.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(categories);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ThreadCategory> getCategoryById(@PathVariable long id) {
        Optional<ThreadCategory> category = threadCategoryService.findById(id);
        if(category.isPresent()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(category.get());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @GetMapping("/title/{title}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<List<ThreadCategory>>> getCategoriesByTitle(@PathVariable String title) {
        Optional<List<ThreadCategory>> categories = threadCategoryService.findByName(title);
        if(categories.isPresent()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(categories);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createCategory(@RequestBody ThreadCategory category) {
        ThreadCategory created = threadCategoryService.createCategory(category);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(created);
    }
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCategory(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody ThreadCategory category) {
        return threadCategoryService.findById(id)
                .map(categoryToUpdate -> {
                    categoryToUpdate.setName(category.getName());
                    categoryToUpdate.setDescription(category.getDescription());
                    threadCategoryService.createCategory(category);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(category);
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCategory(@PathVariable Long id) {
        threadCategoryService.deleteCategoryById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Категория удалена");
    }

}



Your security config doesn't really make sense as you do permitAll for everything. The 401 can only come from your filter and probably indicates an issue with your JWT token (or abscence there of). Your filter is doing too much, just parse the JWT if it is there and set the context, if it isn't don't parse and continue. Let Spring Security bother about the rest.

You should also add /api/v1/forum/threads (without any slashes) to the security exceptions in the SecurityConfig and the JwtFilter, currently that configurations set as public only the paths that has a suffix.
